# Is there a replace function/script in Sass to swap CSS properties?

Tags: css, function, sass, right-to-left

I'm working on a right-to-left solution in Sass.

So for example, if the original style is:

```
#foo {
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

...the function/script will run through looking for floats and padding-lefts and replace the styles with:

```
#foo {
  float: right;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

I already have a solution using mixins, like this:

```
@mixin float($origin: left) {
  @if $origin == left {
    @if $rtl { float: right; }
    @else    { float: left; }
  } @else {
    @if $rtl { float: left; }
    @else    { float: right; }
  }
}

@mixin padding-left($value) {
  padding-right: $value;
}

#foo {
  @include float(left);
  @include padding-left(10px);
}
```

...but is there a way to do this without having to replace all reversible properties with includes?

Comment: No, but this shouldn't be that hard with find and replace in your text editor.

Comment: The CSS needs to be dynamically generated through Sass.
It is not a simple case of find and replace.

Comment: I meant find and replace the explicit declarations with your mixins.

Comment: Fair enough, but I specifically said I'm looking for a non-mixin solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a variable so you can set the direction in one place, but Sass doesn't have the ability to alter existing CSS based on rules you set.

```
$direc: left; 

div {
  float: $direc;
  padding-#{$direc}: 10px;
}
```